# How to treat custom MongoDB queries in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm porting a webserver from python to node.js and one of the capabilities that server must have is to receive a POST containing information about a MongoDB query, and send the result of the query to the webpage. The query may or may not contain a filter, a projection, a limit and a sort. In python we can do it like this:

(In the examples below command_name equals to 'find')

```
command = getattr(collection, command_name)

cmd_filter = loads(filter_str) if filter_str else None
projection = loads(projection_str) if projection_str else None
limit = loads(limit_str) if limit_str else 0
sort = [(elt['key'], elt['order']) for elt in loads(sort_str)] if sort_str else None

response = command(filter=cmd_filter, projection=projection, sort=sort, limit=limit)
```

But I'm having trouble finding a way to do it in node.js, I've tried stuff like this:

```
command_name = req.body['command']
command = collection[command_name]

command = filter_str != undefined ? collection[command_name](JSON.parse(filter_str)) : collection[command_name]
command = projection_str != undefined ? command['project'](JSON.parse(projection_str)) : command
command = sort_str != undefined ? command['sort'](JSON.parse(sort_str)) : command
command = limit_str != undefined ? command['limit'](JSON.parse(limit_str)) : command

response = command.toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err

    console.log(result)
})
```

But it doesn't work. I get a `MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad order array [2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code not working is the least of your problems here. I don't know if you realize but a user may execute any command on the database with your API. I don't know if there is such a name but you have a Mongo injection vulnerability. I have never seen anything like that before, explicitly running user provided random methods with random data on a live database.

Search for Mongoose pagination, sorting etc. for REST APIs in Node and you will find a lot of info on how to do it properly.

There are some modules that can help you with that:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginator
- https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention in the post that this is an internal application for the company. If someone uses this application maliciously we will either find them easily, or we have bigger problems than someone messing with this db.